# array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method

Tags: opengl, jogl

Does anyone know why this error is being thrown?

I thought I am binding to `VBO` when I use `glEnableVertexAttribArray`?

```
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkBufferObject(GL4bcImpl.java:39146)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkArrayVBOBound(GL4bcImpl.java:39178)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glVertexAttribPointer(GL4bcImpl.java:37371)
```

This is my code to draw ..

```
public void draw(final GL2ES2 gl, Matrix4f projectionMatrix, Matrix4f viewMatrix, int shaderProgram, final Vec3 position, final float angle) {

    // enable glsl
    gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // enable alpha
    gl.glEnable(GL2ES2.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL2ES2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2ES2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // get handle to glsl variables
    mPositionHandle = gl.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");
    setmColorHandle(gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor"));
    mProj = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mProj");
    mView = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mView");
    mModel = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mModel");

    // perform translations
    getModelMatrix().loadIdentity();
    getModelMatrix().translate(new Vec3(position.x * 60.0f, position.y * 60.0f, position.z * 60.0f));
    getModelMatrix().rotate(angle, 0, 0, 1);

    // set glsl variables
    gl.glUniform4fv(getmColorHandle(), 1, getColorArray(), 0);
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mProj, 1, true, projectionMatrix.getValues(), 0);
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mView, 1, true, viewMatrix.getValues(), 0);
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mModel, 1, true, getModelMatrix().getValues(), 0);

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);


    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
        getmPositionHandle(), 
        COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
        GL2ES2.GL_FLOAT, 
        false,
        vertexStride, 0L); // This is the line that throws error

    // Draw the square
    gl.glDrawElements(
        GL2ES2.GL_TRIANGLES, 
        drawOrder.length,
        GL2ES2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 
        0L);



    // Disable vertex array
    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    gl.glDisable(GL2ES2.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(I've never used OpenGL with Java, so I'll use C/C++ code, but I hope it will come across well)

You do not create or bind a Vertex Buffer Object.

First, use `glGenBuffers` to create a buffer, as so:

```
GLuint bufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
```

This allocates a handle and stores it in `bufferID`.

Then, bind the buffer:

```
glBindBuffers(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
```

This makes it the "current" buffer to use.

Next, fill the buffer with data. Assuming `vertices` is an array that stores your vertex coordinates, in flat format, with three floats per vertex:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), &vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

This actually puts the data in GPU memory.

Then enable the attribute array and set the pointer:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
```

This will make the data in `vertices` available for shader programs under the vertex attribute location of `mPositionHandle`.

The second-to-last parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` is `stride`. In this example, it is `0`, because the buffer contains only vertex position data. If you want to pack both vertex position data and color data in the same buffer, as so:

```
v1.positionX v1.positionY v1.positionZ v1.colorR v1.colorG v1.colorB
v2.positionX ...
```

you will need to use a non-zero `stride`. `stride` specifies the offset between one attribute and the next of the same type; with stride of `0`, they are assumed to be tightly packed. In this case, you'll want to set a stride of `sizeof(GLfloat) * 6`, so that after reading one vertex's position, it will skip the color data to arrive at the next vertex, and similarily for colors.

```
// (create, bind and fill vertex buffer here)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(location_handle_of_position_data);
glVertexAttribPointer(location_handle_of_position_data, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(location_handle_of_color_data);
glVertexAttribPointer(location_handle_of_color_data, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
```

The last parameter is the offset to the first attribute - the first color attribute starts after the third float.

Other considerations:

- You should look into using Vertex Array Objects. It might or might not work without them, but by standard they are required, and they simplify the code in any case.
- For the sake of simplicity, this example code stores color data in floats, but for real use bytes are preferable.

Comment: I've tried to `glGenBuffers`, `glBindBuffer` and `glBufferData` before `glEnableVertexAttribArray` but I get this error which is very similar to original .. `element vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method`

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Try also binding a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). Some implementations will not let you do anything without one.

Answer (score 0):

`glVertexAttribPointer()` specifies that data for the attribute should be pulled from the **currently bound** vertex buffer, using the parameters specified. So you need to call:

```
gl.glBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, ...);
```

**before** you call `glVertexAttribPointer()`.

`glEnableVertexAttribArray()` specifies that an array should be used for the vertex attribute. Otherwise, a constant value, specified with calls like `glVertexAttrib4f()` is used. But it does not specify that the array is in a buffer. And even more importantly, there's no way `glVertexAttribPointer()` would know **which** buffer to use for the attribute unless you bind a specific buffer.